# * operator and type converters

Tags: c#, type-conversion, operators

I have the following.  It works as expected:

```
using System;
namespace Whatever {  
  public class DoubleWrapper {
    public double Payload { get; set; }
    public DoubleWrapper(double payload) {
      this.Payload = payload;
    }
    public static implicit operator DoubleWrapper(double x) {
      DoubleWrapper r = new DoubleWrapper(x);
      return r;
    }
    public static implicit operator double(DoubleWrapper wrapper) {
      double r = wrapper.Payload;
      return r;
    }
    public DoubleWrapper Times(DoubleWrapper multiplyByMe) {
      DoubleWrapper r = this * multiplyByMe;  // does compile
      return r;
    }
  }
}
```

However, if I replace "double" with "Complex", I get a compile error:

```
using System;
using System.Numerics;
namespace Whatever {
  public class ComplexWrapper {
    public Complex Payload { get; set; }
    public ComplexWrapper(Complex payload) {
      this.Payload = payload;
    }
    public static implicit operator ComplexWrapper(Complex x) {
      ComplexWrapper r = new ComplexWrapper(x);
      return r;
    }
    public static implicit operator Complex(ComplexWrapper wrapper) {
      Complex r = wrapper.Payload;
      return r;
    }
    public ComplexWrapper Times(ComplexWrapper multiplyByMe) {
      ComplexWrapper r = this * multiplyByMe; // ERROR: Operator '*' cannot be applied to operands of type Whatever.ComplexWrapper and Whatever.ComplexWrapper.
      return r;
    }
```

The work-around is not hard -- I can replace the line like this:

```
      ComplexWrapper r = this.Payload * multiplyByMe; //WORKS
```

I did verify that the * symbol works for both double and System.Numerics.Complex.  It does:

```
namespace SomewhereElse { // different namespace
  public static class TestTimes {  // builds just fine
    public static void Products() {
      double x1 = 4;
      double x2 = 5;
      double product = x1 * x2;
      Complex z1 = new Complex(3, 4);
      Complex z2 = new Complex(3, -4);
      Complex zProduct = z1 * z2;
    }
  }
}
```

Why does my DoubleWrapper class build, but not my ComplexWrapper?

Answer (score 1):

On your block 1 the type is implicitly converted to a `double` so multiplying works but on your block 2 there's no multiplication operator.

If you add the following code on your 2nd class the error will disappear.

```
    public static ComplexWrapper operator *(ComplexWrapper a, ComplexWrapper b)
    {
        var complex = a.Payload * b.Payload;
        return complex;
    }
```

**EDIT : refined answer / 2nd approach**

The compiler seems to promote that type to `ComplexWrapper` which is what produces that error.

By simply casting `this` to `Complex` the error will also disappear :

```
    public ComplexWrapper Times(ComplexWrapper multiplyByMe)
    {
        ComplexWrapper r = (Complex)this * multiplyByMe;
        // ERROR: Operator '*' cannot be applied to operands of type Whatever.ComplexWrapper and Whatever.ComplexWrapper.
        return r;
    }
```